# Google OAuth 2.0 invalid_request, Missing Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, oauth

I cannot authorize Google OAuth on ios, safari always say

400 That's an error.

Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri:
Missing scheme: com.googleusercontent.apps.984813079630-3lmlrubo9345ng4qhtf62ud1i02m6ta8

[image]
I have checked API Key, Client_ID, client_secret on Google Console page many times and also create url scheme in the xcode.

Here are my Swift code:

> oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
>                   consumerKey:    "xxxxx-3lmlrubo9345ng4qhtf62ud1i02m6ta8.apps.googleusercontent.com",
>                   consumerSecret: "xxxtg6qslUOC2np1sBg0hnWgBcpZb4",
>                   authorizeUrl:   "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
>                   responseType:   "token"
>           )
>           let handle = oauthswift.authorize(
>                   withCallbackURL: URL(string: "com.googleusercontent.apps.984813079630-3lmlrubo9345ng4qhtf62ud1i02m6ta8")!,
>                   scope: "profile", state:"GOOGLE",
>                   success: { credential, response, parameters in
>                       print(credential.oauthToken)
>                       // Do your request
>                   },
>                   failure: { error in
>                       print(error.localizedDescription)
>                   }
>           )

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty simple fix for this issue:
just set prefix before your schema.

Example:
your schema parameter:

```
com.googleusercontent.apps.984813079630-3lmlrubo9345ng4qhtf62ud1i02m6ta8
```

the identifier of your iOS application:

```
net.the-red-queen.www
```

so, value for your redirect URI parameter is:

```
net.the-red-queen.www:com.googleusercontent.apps.984813079630-3lmlrubo9345ng4qhtf62ud1i02m6ta8
```

Comment: I wonder whether Google changed the scheme format later on, because some tutorials do not mention this. This worked great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think the actual issue is that you didn't specify a full URI. (The schema doesn't have a colon and then a path.) Try making your redirect_uri look something like the following (properly encoded, of course):

```
com.googleusercontent.apps.984813079630-3lmlrubo9345ng4qhtf62ud1i02m6ta8:/oauth
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably recheck the Google Dev Console. Your clientID might be wrongly registered for [Javascript Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) rather than [Mobile Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift)

Comment: I checked again and also deleted the auto generated key for Web
It still does not work

Comment: I changed withCallbackURL: URL(string: http://localhost
them it allow to login google but cannot reopen the ios app

Comment: Did you add GoogleService-Info.plist to your app and a URL Type with REVERSED_CLIENT_ID to your app plist? Make sure your reversed Id matches with your iOS client Id on your Google Dev Console

Comment: absolutely yes
anw, I have changed the scheme to com.googleusercontent.apps.984813079630-3lmlrubo9345ng4qhtf62ud1i02m6ta8:/oauth then it work now
but another problem happens : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558561/google-oauth-2-0-invalid-client-unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing an Android client, and this information helped, but wasn't quite what I needed.  I found that I had to make the redirect uri a little differently.

Take the uri that you're using as a target on the phone (usually the package name, but it *can* be different if re-defined in the applicationId in the app's build.gradle file).

Append this at the end of the target: `:/oauth2callback`

So my package is `com.fooboy.testapp3`.  Add the above bit and the redirect uri becomes:

`com.foobly.testapp3:/oauth2callback`.

There are a lot of other things that need to be just right (especially in the google api console), but this was the final trick for me.

Good luck (you'll need it)!