# Google OAuth 2.0 invalid_client Unauthorized

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, oauth-2.0

I used this code to authorize Google+ via OAuth 2.0

> oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
>                   consumerKey:    "984813079630-f828a92sqtl5lgumd4kgp9i30bs9og09.apps.googleusercontent.com",
>                   consumerSecret: "AIzaSyD13MBv78yWIjl4TX9jOOT9AWuEkYdVSPQ",
>                   authorizeUrl:   "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
>                   accessTokenUrl: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
>                   responseType:   "code"
>           )
>
> ```
>     let handle = oauthswift.authorize(
>             withCallbackURL: URL(string: "com.googleusercontent.apps.984813079630-f828a92sqtl5lgumd4kgp9i30bs9og09:/oauth")!,
>             scope: "profile", state:"GOOGLE",
>             success: { credential, response, parameters in
>                 print(credential.oauthToken)
>                 // Do your request
>             },
>             failure: { error in
>                 print(error.localizedDescription)
>                 print((error as OAuthSwiftError).errorUserInfo)
>             }
>     )
> ```

but the result always failed

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OAuthSwiftError error -11.)
>   ["request": https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token, "error": Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=401 "invalid_client Unauthorized"
>   UserInfo={Response-Body={  "error": "invalid_client", 
>   "error_description": "Unauthorized" } ,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token,
>   Response-Headers={
>       "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
>       "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
>       "Content-Length" = 81;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Thu, 15 Jun 2017 04:25:10 GMT";
>       Expires = "Thu, 15 Jun 2017 04:25:10 GMT";
>       Server = GSE;
>       Vary = "Origin, X-Origin";
>       "Www-Authenticate" = "Bearer realm=\"https://accounts.google.com/\"";
>       "alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"38,37,36,35\"";
>       "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
>       "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
>       "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block"; }, OAuthSwiftError.response= { URL:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token } { status code: 401,
>   headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
>       "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
>       "Content-Length" = 81;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Thu, 15 Jun 2017 04:25:10 GMT";
>       Expires = "Thu, 15 Jun 2017 04:25:10 GMT";
>       Server = GSE;
>       Vary = "Origin, X-Origin";
>       "Www-Authenticate" = "Bearer realm=\"https://accounts.google.com/\"";
>       "alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"38,37,36,35\"";
>       "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
>       "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
>       "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block"; } }, OAuthSwiftError.response.data=<7b0a2022 6572726f 72223a20 22696e76
>   616c6964 5f636c69 656e7422 2c0a2022 6572726f 725f6465 73637269
>   7074696f 6e223a20 22556e61 7574686f 72697a65 64220a7d 0a>,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=invalid_client Unauthorized}]

Could you please correct it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must remove replace withCallbackURL `"com.googleusercontent.apps.984813079630-f828a92sqtl5lgumd4kgp9i30bs9og09:/oauth"` with `"your.bundle.id:/oauth2Callback"`

Commentary from demo OAuthSwift:

> For googgle the redirect_uri should match your this syntax:
>   your.bundle.id:/oauth2Callback
>
> In plist define a url schem with: your.bundle.id

After these changes, I still had this problem. Found solution:

**I removed the customerSecret by an empty string then.. it worked.**

I hope to help you with my answer above!